# Wrong map center in iOS using nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

In iOS when I put marker and mapView location, the map does not display centered, but if I move the phone to landscape and rotate again to portrait the map center displays fine.
In Android works fine.

You can get more information in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/322

Comment: Did you try setting the lat and long on mapReady event?

Comment: Yes, the positioning works, but with a bit of displacement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have personally faced this and discovered that it's basically a layout problem on iOS. The `height` and `width` attribute values supplied to the MapView's XML element are somewhat differently treated by iOS. The solution to our problem, as described in the question itself is `resizing` the map on runtime (as rotating the screen makes it go through a resizing routine). Applying this absurd logic at the beginning of the map render, solves the problem.

**This is how I did it:**

Provide the `width` value of the MapView in XML:

```
<maps:mapView width="100%" mapReady="onMapReady" />
```

and set the `height` of the map inside `onMapReady` method, with a 100 millisecond delay.

```
/* if you want to set height in DIP */

setTimeout(() => this.mapView.height = 500, 100);
```

or if you want to set height in percentage

```
/* [0.85 means 85% here] */

setTimeout(() => this.mapView.height = {
    unit: '%',
    value: 0.85
}, 100);
```

100 millisecond delay makes it go through the `resize` effect. Tested on iOS 12.1